# User downloading packages ends up seeing folders with the package's contents instead of a package?

Tags: macos, logic

Does anyone know why someone downloading a package from a website (in this case, the package is a Logic Pro project file) ends up seeing a folder that contains the package's contents instead of the original package (which prevents them from double-clicking the package to open the file in Logic Pro)?

Comment: Is this a user upload or a site distributing Logic projects?

Answer (score 3):

Zip it first.

Don't try to send a Logic project package over the internet or via a 'drop'-type server, it will break the package & file perms inside it.

Note: This also applies to storing Logic projects & other 'bundles' on non-Apple disk formats, such as ExFAT.

Comment: Exactly. Storing the files and folder structure on a foreign file system ruins all sorts of permissions and metadata needed for the full experience to work correctly.

Comment: @bmike - Thanks. I added a note re 'foreign' disk formats too.

Comment: The project file is part of a folder containing about 10 Logic project files (saved as packages). That folder is zipped. Downloading that zipped folder and unzipping still breaks the packages inside.

Comment: Was it initially zipped on a Mac-formatted drive? If it was e.g. ExFAT, the damage could have already happened.

Comment: Yes it was zipped on the internal drive of a new Mac mini M1 with Monterey, factory-formatted APFS.

Comment: OK… so… what's the intermediate service [not that I think anything can break it whilst it's zipped] & what is the receiver unzipping it to? …and, are you zipping just with the Mac's built-in structure or something like BetterZip, Keka etc?